# Sum elements of a list (datetime) in one value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm searching to concatenate elements of a list.

For example:
`l=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

i want to have :

`l_concatenated=45`

My code is :

```
  from datetime import *
  data=[[datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 2, 810000), 159],
  [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 2, 811000), 159],
  [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 108000), 159],
  [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 108000), 159],
  [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 182000), 159],
  [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 182000), 159],
  [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 326000), 159],
  [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 326000), 159]]

  date=[i[0] for i in data]
  interval=[b-a for a,b in zip(date[:-1],date[1:])]
  sorted_interval=[item for item in interval if item!=timedelta(0)]
  # It doesn't function and just give wrong information
  interval_concatenated=[ko[i]+ko[i+1] for i in range(len(sorted_interval)-1)]
```

Edit : I need to recuperate the average of the interval between 2 dates. 
with `interval=[b-a for a,b in zip(date[:-1],date[1:])]` i set the interval between the 2 consecutives values. 
For example : 
It may look `interval=[timedelta(0, 0, 297000),timedelta(0, 0, 297000),timedelta(0, 0, 123000),timedelta(0, 1, 300000)]` and i want the average of interval.

Comment: @BartoszKP Sorry i did a mistake, english isn't my native language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can calculate intervals between consecutive dates using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
intervals = [d2[0] - d1[0] for (d1, d2) in zip(data, data[1:])]
```

Then, get the total `timedelta`:

```
total_interval = sum(intervals, timedelta(0, 0, 0))
```

And finally, calculate the average:

```
average_interval = total_interval / len(intervals)
```

Comment: Thanx a lot ! i really don't try to use sum() I don't think it can use with a list Nice trick !

Comment: @Jguillot Of course you can use it with a list :) I've tested the code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for this:

```
import datetime
import time

data=[[datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 2, 810000), 159],
      [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 2, 811000), 159],
      [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 108000), 159],
      [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 108000), 159],
      [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 182000), 159],
      [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 182000), 159],
      [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 326000), 159],
      [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 15, 28, 3, 326000), 159]]

date = [time.mktime(i[0].timetuple()) for i in data]

average = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sum(date)/len(date))
```

First convert datetime object to [Posix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), then calculate the average and finally convert it back.

Comment: I'm looking for something different, i edited my question. I need the average of the interval between two consecutives date. But your answer give me some ideas.